# Button in list from Javascript loop throws back the of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I got this javascript loop which generates a unordered list with maybe 50 list items.. Now I want to put a button in every list item which stores the content in a database. Think retweet.

I figured out a way which is put the button and the content from the listitem within a hidden input in the loop but that seems like a bad shortcut. Like this:

```
html += "<form action=\"add.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + listitem + "\" name=\"item\"\/>";
    html += "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"repost\" \/><\/form>";
```

Using jQuery seems much more subtle and more like the right thing to do. I've gotten this far:

```
    $("button").click(function() 
    var value = ($(this).text());
$.post('add.php',{value:value};
});
```

With a button in the loop instead of the input. But I can't even get the jQuery to response to the button click. Is there anyway this is possible or should I just go with the shortcut?!

The loop =

```
  var html = "<li><h2 class=\"postTitle\">" + title + " <\/h2>";
                html += "<p id=\"postText\" class=\"postText\">" + text + "</p></li>";
$('#Content').append($(html));
```

And the html where the loop ends up:

```
<ul id="list">
<div id="Content">
    &nbsp;
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the "button" element -> `$(this).text()`? Give us html of this `<button>` to be clarify

Comment: Its a simple <button>Name</button>. I thought $(this) would give me the list content but I might be wrong?!

Comment: could you give whole you code (HTML + JavaScript) this helps us to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

From the code above the jQuery selector being used ("button") will not match anything in your code as you've used an input for the button; try:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
    ...
});
```

Ideally use a more targeted selector as I presume you don't want every submit button to do this :)

Comment: Like I said under the jQuery code, when I tried the jQuery I switched the input to a button in the loop. And I'm just using the button selector now to show what I mean. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should read the whole question :) A way you could go forward would be to create the dynamic HTML with jQuery and then use its [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) API to get the value e.g. `var input = $("<button></button>").attr("type", "submit").data("item", listItem)` and then `$("input[type=submit]").click(function () { $.post("add.php", { value: $(this).data("item") }) });`. This also has the added benefit of keeping data out of the DOM :)

Comment: Where should I put the code?! "item" and listItem should be replaced with li?! This will get the content from just one correct list item and not all?! Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: The [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) API can be viewed as a 'global' object that contains key-value pairs of data for each element (a unique ID is generated for each element).  The value that you previously had in the hidden field should be added to the data under a key of your choice.  Could you possibly post the full HTML of your code? This will help us find a definitive solution for you :-)

Comment: Just to clarify: Is it the text within `postText` that you wish to post? Also, do you want a button added immediately after the `p` element or after the text within the `p` element?

Comment: Yeah, and the postTitle as well if it's possible. After the p element. The help is appreciated!

Comment: If you give each `li` a specific class, say "list-class", then something like the following may work:  `$("li.list-class").each(function () {  var $li = $(this),  $btn = $("<button></button").attr("type", "submit");  $btn.data("title", $li.children(".postTitle").html());  $btn.data("text", $li.children(".postText").html());  $btn.click(function () {  var title = $(this).data("title"),  txt = $(this).data("text");  }) $btn.appendTo($li); }) `    This will iterate over all the `li` elements and add a button in based on the `li`'s contents.

Comment: I have added the code to the html page but the buttons doesn't appear!? And how can I give each `li` a specific class?! Man, I'm starting to feel like a complete fool.

Comment: It's probably my fault for not understanding :) When you create the HTML string just do `<li class="my-class">`.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/bNc67/); it makes it clearer. Plus I think I had some errors in my JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your button a unique id?
resulting in:

```
$('#myId').click(function(){
//your code here
});
```

That is much better to specify.
You can also try to give it a class and an id

```
$('.myClass').click(function(){
var myButton = $(this).attr('id');
if(myButton == 'myId'){ do this} else if(myButton == 'myOtherId'){do this}

});
```

that way you can handle several buttons in one function, and if there are many buttons if statements will make your code look all messed up and you can use a select case :)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you send your data via AJAX `$.post`, you should prevent submitting a form:

```
$("button[type=submit]").click(function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.preventDefault();
    // or in the end of handler
    return false;
});
```

Second, `<input>` and `<button>` elements will return nothing in `$(elem).text()`, to get a value you should use `$(elem).val()` method.

Third, use the **id** attribute for HTML elements, this will help you manage DOM easier.

Comment: Sound logical, but I dont get a response from jQuery when I have a button in the loop. I have tried using id's and alert to see if it works but it doesn't give an alert even thou another button on the site which isn't in the loop gives an alert.